# Is there any free Tab Control for Blazor Web Assembly to develop a C# Web application

Tags: .net-core, blazor-webassembly

I am in need of a Free Tab Control like functionality which could be used in a Web application inside Blazor + Web Assembly components.

Is there any free Tab Control for Blazor Web Assembly to develop a C# Web application.

Comment: Nothing as free a writing your own. Or [Copy/Paste from the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-6.0#pass-data-across-a-component-hierarchy)

Comment: Thanks, Henk for sharing these details. In am in need to implement a functionality where need to open TAB's at runtime on click on Menu link.  For example, Search link in Menu bar, once user click on search and put user id and hit ENTER , then a new tab should get opened with user details. then if user search another user, likewise another TAB should get opened and so on up to 10 TAB's max. where business can see multi user details by click on corresponding TAB or closing it to have an option to add more tabs with more user details.